# Teamcity to trigger builds when automatically detected dependencies change

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, teamcity, nuget

We're using Teamcity for continuous integration of a large set of Visual C++ projects, with  Nuget to manage dependencies between projects.

All projects are build in Teamcity using a simple meta-runner that:

1. restores Nuget from the Teamcity Nuget artifact server
2. updates Nuget with newer versions
3. Runs MSBuild to complete the build
4. Creates a new Nuget file for the new projects, and publishes it to the Teamcity Nuget server.

When you look at a build configuration that is built like this, you can see that Teamcity detects the Nuget dependencies automatically - if I select a build that has completed, I can see that under the dependencies tab it lists all the Nugets that the build consumed, without me needing to specify them in the build configuration's "Dependencies" settings. Teamcity also shows - in the build configuration list - which build configurations have pending changes from upstream dependencies.

Now I want that Teamcity, when it sees such pending changes, will trigger a build to verify that the upstream changes have not broken the downstream projects.

I've looked at the Nuget dependency trigger but it requires me to specify the packages IDs that I want to track. But dependency packages can change - they are not specified in Teamcity but in the Visual Studio project files, and we want to move the dependencies around (mostly to decrease cross-dependencies), so I don't want to hard code the dependency structure into Teamcity.

Any idea how to get Teamcity to act on the dependency changes it detects automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such possibility out of the box at the moment. Check out http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-30006 and upvote, so we may get Jetbrains to implement this much needed functionality.

Another possibility is to create a trigger plugin as such: http://rockycode.com/blog/writing-custom-build-trigger-teamcity/. If you end up writing your own plugin, be sure to share it with the community =)